# How can I convert a QString of numbers to an array of int?

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion, qstring

I have a `QString` containing a series of numbers for example

```
QString path = "11100332001 234 554 9394";
```

I want to iterate over the variable length string

```
for (int i=0; i<path.length(); i++){

}
```

and be able to acces each number as an `int` individually.

I haven't been able to do so however. **Question**: How can I convert a `QString` of numbers to an array of `int`?

I know I can convert the `QString` to an `int` using `path.toInt()` but that doesn't help me.

When trying to convert it to a char first I get an error: `cannot convert 'const QChar to char'`.

```
for (int i=0; i<path.length(); i++){
        char c = path.at(i);
        int j = atoi(&c);
        //player->movePlayer(direction);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get every character (QChar) with the [] operator and use the digitValue() method on them to get the integer.

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke: in that case you should mark this answer as the solution, using the green check mark.

Comment: Why the down vote? This answers the question asked by @Thomas.

Answer (score 10):

you can use `split` to obtain an array of substrings separated by the separator you want in this case it's a space , here is an example :

```
QString str("123 457 89");

QStringList list = str.split(" ",QString::SkipEmptyParts);

foreach(QString num, list)
    cout << num.toInt() << endl;
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to the one by @antoyo as it is less cumbersome

Answer (score 3):

Use [QTextStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#QTextStream):

```
QString str = "123 234   23123  432";
QTextStream stream(&str);
QList<int> array;
while (!stream.atEnd()) {
    int number;
    stream >> number;
    array.append(number);
}
```

Comment: it is; strictly it is; and your answer is strictly right but it's not a answer to my question so I guess what you're trying to say is that my title isn't specific enough? fair enough

Comment: OK, what is your question then?

Comment: I want to acces the individual numbers of a series of numbers in an QString; thx for changing the title.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the answer by Antoyo myself but I ran into an issue today.
digitValue() is not the same as comparing a char in C using atoi like the op Thomas was trying to do. So while Thomas was trying to do this:

```
for (int i=0; i<path.length(); i++){
        char c = path.at(i);
        int j = atoi(&c);
        //player->movePlayer(direction);
    }
```

with digitValue() it would have become this:

```
for (int i=0; i<path.length(); i++){
        int j = path.at(i).digitValue();
        //player->movePlayer(direction);
    }
```

However this does not have the expected results if there are any letters in the string. For example in C, if the string has a mix of Letters and numbers then any char you use atoi on will return a 0 in place of a letter. digitValue() however does not return 0 for a letter. It may be a good idea to do a check for isDigit() first if you have any concerns about letters ending up in your string and the final result would look like this:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i=0; i<path.length(); i++){
        if (path.at(i).isDigit())
            j = path.at(i).digitValue();
        else
            j = 0;
        //player->movePlayer(direction);
    }
```

This may not have been a concern for the OP but since this is one of the top Google results for getting numbers from a string in QT it might help someone else, especially if you're trying to get a QT application to behave the same as some embedded C code on a device.